# Elements removal from list

Tags: lisp

What I have to do is removing some elements from the list,the 1st,2nd,4th,8th,elements on positions power of 2.I figured out that the easyest way for me to solve this is to construct how the result list should look like without destroying the original list.Here's my code but it doesn't work yet,I'm getting a type error.I'm using `contor` to know with which element of the list I'm working with an `counter` to specify only the position from which the elements should be removed.My question is what am I doing wrong and how can it be fixed?

```
(defun remo(l)
  (defparameter e ())
  (setq contor 0)
  (setq counter 0)
  (dolist (elem l) (
                    (cond
                     (
                      ((or (< (expt 2 contor) counter) (> (expt 2 contor) counter)) 
                       ((push elem e) (setq contor (+ 1 contor))))
                     ))
                    (setq counter (+1 counter))
    )
    )
  (print e)
  )
```

Comment: You have an extra set of parentheses around the body of `dolist`.

Comment: You should bind local variables using `let`, not `defparameter` and `setq`.

Comment: If you want to increment multiple variables during your iteration, you should probably use `do` or `loop` rather than `dolist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defun remo (l)
  (do ((power-of-2 1)
       (counter 1 (1+ counter))
       (result ())
       (sublist l (cdr sublist)))
      ((null sublist) (nreverse result))
    (if (= counter power-of-2)
        (setq power-of-2 (* 2 power-of-2))
      (push (car sublist) result))))

(remo '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
=> (3 5 6 7 9 10)
```

Comment: `((null sublist) (return (nreverse result))` is checking if the list is empty,right? why do you return the `nreverse` then?

Comment: @Matt result has been built up (in reverse order) during the iteration.  `(nreverse result)` returns the the result that you actually want.  It's a common idiom in Common Lisp to built up a list in reverse order and the return its reverse.

Comment: There's no need to `(return ...)` here, though;  the form in that position is the value of the `do` expression, so it would be more simply `((null sublist) (nreverse result))`.

Answer (score 0):

I already improved another of your attempts at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20711170/31615, but since you stated the real problem here, I propose the following solution:

```
(defun remove-if-index-power-of-2 (list)
  (loop :for element :in list
        :for index :upfrom 1        ; correct for language: "1st" is index 0
        :unless (power-of-2-p index)
        :collect element))

(defun power-of-2-p (number)
  "Determines whether number, which is assumed to be a nonnegative
integer, is a power of 2 by counting the bits."
  (declare (type (integer 0 *) number))
  (= 1 (logcount number)))
```